# Which in graph theory book do you recommend for a Biologist?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, biology

I need a book in Graph Theory for my Thesis project in Biology (6 months from now). I have reasonable mathematical knowledge. The book must be strict but not as complicated as an advanced book. The idea is to take this book as an introduction and progressively dwell using a more complicated one (Diestel's, mainly). Focus: Colouring and Cographs.

Thanks!

Comment: The only graph theory book that I used many years ago is [West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Graph-Theory-2nd-Edition/dp/0130144002). You might find it useful.

Comment: The classic is Bondy and Murthy : [Graph theory](http://www.springer.com/new+&+forthcoming+titles+%28default%29/book/978-1-84628-969-9) which is essentially for undergraduate math students.  But I have never seen a book specifically on cographs.  That mostly in the papers (though the Wikipedia page on cographs cover the basics pretty well).  I'm in bioinformatics and have recently found out about applications of cographs in phylogeny.  Can I ask you what your interest for cographs is ?